# Recognizing when an Ajax request's value has increased

Tags: ajax, get

I'm using an Ajax request to call numbers from a php file. Currently I'm repeatedly appending the numbers to the page like so..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: '/number.php',
        type: 'get',
        success: function (output) {
            $(document.body).append(output);        }
      });
    }, 1000);
});
```

The number will increase every hour or so, currently the output looks something like:

> 11 11 11 11 11 11 11

What I would really like to do is trigger a Jquery function when the number increases. I've been trying to find answers online but I'm not entirely sure what to search for.

- The number **will not** increase by "1" the example is "11" the next number will be larger but it could be 100 or 328932.
- Every number doesn't necessarily need to be appended to the page anything is fine.

How would I detect when the number has increased and when it does trigger a Jquery function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just store the value in a variable available to the scope of the ajax call.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // variable to store current value
    var currentValue = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/number.php',
            type: 'get',
            success: function (output) {
                // parse returned value to integer
                var intVal = parseInt(output);
                // make comparison
                if (intVal > currentValue) {
                    currentValue = intVal;
                    $(document.body).append(output);
                } else {
                    // do something else or nothing at all
                }
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, everyone offered useful advice but yours is the once I'm using, the comments were most enlightening.

Comment: @Leviathan Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you receive a number store this in a global variable.
define this before the ready function.

```
var lastNumber;
```

So that in your code when you make the next request you can compare the number returned with the last number. if it's greater then do your function.

```
if(output > lastNumber) {
    // call function here
}

lastNumber = output;
```

Comment: Although I marked another answer as correct I took on board your input, especially the part about defining "before the ready function". Thank you very much,

Comment: There is no reason to define before `ready()` function. Putting within `ready()` but before `setInterval()` is sufficient to make the variable available to the scope of ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

If the output is really just a string with the number, then:

```
var lastNumber = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: '/number.php',
        type: 'get',
        success: function (output) {
            var newNumber = parseInt(output);
            if (newNumber > lastNumber) {
              lastNumber = newNumber;
              yourCustomFunction(newNumber);
            }
        }
      });
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks I learned something from reviewing your code. I'm only sorry I can only mark one correct answer.